# How to add some pictures under the slideshow on my homepage?

Tags: 7, views

This is how the homepage of our website looks like for now:

[image: home page]

I want to add some pictures under the slideshow (where it says "Welcome"). And if you click any of these pictures, you go to another page on the site (history, tour dates, song texts, ... ).

How do I do this?

Comment: Hey SC-whatever ... Another attempt to get you going with how this site works: you have 3 answers, all 3 of them have 1 upvote from "somebody" ... I cannot imagine there is not even 1 that helped you to answer THIS question. So, according to how things work on this site, it is commonly expected that you"mark" one of those questions as accepted (the green checkbox to the left of each answer). THAT is like saying "thank you" to those who answered, get it? PS: no you do not have to mark "my" answer as accepted, I just want you to learn to be a good site user, ok?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in two way:

Static way:
Create a page, set it as your home page, insert your images in the content of the page and link them manually to each of your pages

Dynamic way:
Create a content type, lets say HomeImage.
Add two CCK Field to this content, one for the image, one for the link
Then follow @Shabir solution...

Comment: how do you link the images manually to each of my pages? I want to apologize for my noob behaviour :) , but I really can't do this unless it's explained to me step by step, I don't want to be rude, but maybe I can chat with someone or something ?

Comment: @S.C: I fully understand your step-by-step request ... it seems to confirm what I mean with "learn to walk before trying to fly", which is also why I wrote my answer targeted to a Drupal-noob audience (no need to apologize, everybody ever started with Drupal with a background like you now seem to have).

Answer (score 1):

For somebody new to Drupal, I recommend you to try to learn to walk before trying to fly. So here are some very basic steps, intended for somebody who's looking for a kind of "Hello Drupal"-page to get started ... Anything in italics refers to Drupal terminology you'll have to get used to ...

- Make sure you are logged in as the user with userid "1". That will ensure you will not get stuck (yet) because of some missing authorizations. So after logging in, you should see an URL like `/user/1`. Later on (when you're more familiar), you should create another user with appropriate "*permissions*", and only use `user/1` if really needed.
- Start with creating a "*node*", by navigating to `/node/add` (= Add new content). Pick whatever "*type*" fits for you, typically something like article or page (to get started).
- Complete the form to edit (create) the node, at least add a "*Title*" and "*Body*" (here you insert "Hello Drupal" for now ...), and hit the <kbd>Save</kbd> button. That will create a new "node", with an url that is something like `/node/x` (x= some digit, if you start a brand new site it is probably '1'). Make sure to memorize the value of "x" (you need it later on).
- Head over to `admin/config/system/site-information`, and find the field labeled "Default Front Page". For this field, enter the value `/node/x` (with "x" the value corresponding the node you created). Then hit the <kbd>Save configuration</kbd> button.
- Now navigate back to your homepage (also called "*Frontpage*"), eg by just clicking on the logo or some link in the upperleft of your site. After doing so, you should see "Hello Drupal" somewhere on that frontpage.
- On your frontpage, you should have some tabs (typically in the middle near the top) with labels such as "View" or "Edit".
- Use the "Edit" tab to start enhancing your (elementary) homepage. At this point, it may well be that by using the edit link, you get an edit form in which the body field is just some kind of HTML file (not a nice WYSIWYG editor). In that case don't worry too much yet, because it's pretty forward to integrate one of the many wysiwyg editors to simplify the editing of such pages (HOW to do that ... is another question ...). So from here use your HTML expertise and your own imagination to enhance the body of your page with images, hyperlinks, etc.

**Next step(s)**:

- at any time you can change your homepage to another "node" (just revisit `admin/config/system/site-information` to change it to anything else).
- there are waaaaay more sophisticated homepages you can create. And using modules such as [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) or [Panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels) you can do amazing things (but that's when you're ready to learn flying ...).

**Homework**:

If you want some type of challenge (extra homework?), try creating a homepage created with [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views), and using a "*Grid*" as the views display, with a title and an image in each cell of such grid, and some hyperlink to another page if you click that link. When you're done, post an extra answer to explain the steps you performed ... and maybe a screenprint of the final result ...

**PS**: all paths mentioned are relative (add them after your domain name to create the URL that applies in your case).

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Drupal,

You can achieve this with following techniques.

1. Install [views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) and all its dependencies.
2. Go to structure create a views of your content types.
3. Select block display instead of page.
4. Display Select image field and in setting click link to original
       content.
5. Now you will see the block in blocks list. Select the block and
   render it in your appropriate region on home page.